# I am not Alien Then who am i?

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle, code

> **Treat me baby who Abode of the good**
>
> **But don't think my origin is asteroid**
>
> but believe me, i am not that alien
>
> **I have traveled Millennium distances**
>
> **but that may not whistler in your ears**
>
> once you know, i am not that alien
>
> **Treat me with longhorns on my head**
>
> **with black color combs for my hairs**
>
> but believe me, i am not that alien
>
> **when you able to see Jupiter in sky,**
>
> **and wander why sky color is blue,**
>
> you will come to know who am i,
>
> but believe me, i am not that alien
>
> Then who am i ?

I would add hints after every 1 hours

Hints :
1)

> These lines do not specify a characteristic but a code.See what seems odd words from above lines.

2)

> See my edited tag Computers

3)

> **but believe me, i am not that alien** lines are added as buffers so you dont deviate from actual object/entity

4)

> See first line carefully biblical meaning of that would be great hint.I think this hint will end up this question.:)

5)

> see bold sentences only those matters and have solution. #1 hint and #4 hint combine them to get solution...

Comment: if you are not *that* alien, then you should be *this* alien

Comment: @Novarg but i would add a hint after every 4 hours :P ..

Comment: Still not getting... CODE with longhorns??? OMG

Comment: @ CoDe i think you are close...next two hints you will crack this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords seem to fit

> Microsoft Windows

Asteroid, Millennium, Longhorn, Jupiter

> All are Windows code names: 2000 SP1 (Asteroid), ME (Millennium edition), Vista (Longhorn), 8 UI (Jupiter).

Comment: perfect......nicely done....but what about remaining clues/codes....if you find them out you will come to know there is also a pattern...anyways great job....

Comment: I've added Asteroid, but I'm not sure about the other clues.

Comment: See i have answered it.....which shows all code names and pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> iOS

?
Millennium and longhorn hint at

> Operating Systems

I am not Alien

> not Android

A further hint is the lower case i that is used in the riddle.

Comment: Great you are bit closer....but nope this isn't an answer...I am thinking whether to add next hint or not...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is

> Mercury?
>  The longhorns is his planetary symbol - you can see it only when the sun is close to the horizon -> the sky is still blue, but already dark enough to make it possible to see jupiter.

Comment: Nope but check i have added Hints added for clarification

Answer (score 2):

Treat me **baby who Abode of the good**->Bible->**Memphis**

But don't think my origin is **asteroid**

but believe me, i am not that alien

I have traveled **Millennium** distances

but that may not **whistler** in your ears

once you know, i am not that alien

Treat me with **longhorns** on my head

with **black** color **comb**s for my hairs

but believe me, i am not that alien

when you able to see **Jupiter** in sky,

and wander why sky color is **blue**,

you will come to know who am i,

but believe me, i am not that alien

Then who am i ?

All are **Microsoft windows codenames** in series

Answer (score 1):

I Guess it is

> X - coordinate ?

I have traveled Millennium distances

> In graphs it travel Millennium distances, no limit of it

Treat me with longhorns on my head

> Also X have longhorns on head

when you able to see Jupiter in sky,

and wander why sky color is blue,

> Not sure but you are able to see jupiter from earth in x - coordinate

Comment: Nope but I have added 5 th hint also take a look at @xyz s answer......

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> LIGHT?

It's not alien in itself, but it can travel from many light years away, doesn't whistle in your ears (that's sound!), and sometimes enables you to see Jupiter in the daytime (if you have a good enough telescope, at least).

Comment: nope what about longhorns on my head with black color combs for my hairs....

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> the sun?

The longhorns might be ancient egyptian.

Comment: Nope i have edited one line, I have traveled Millennium distances.I am afraid efforts are going in wrong direction.Or wait till my next hint